# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of null at resumeVideo

Tags: javascript

Please help me understand why Im getting this error on the console, Im using google chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <video width="600" id"vid">
      <source src="Video/caballeroCorriendo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <button onclick="intervalo();">Iniciar</button>

    <script src="vid.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the js:

```
var video = document.getElementById("vid");

function resumeVideo(){
  video.play();
}

function intervalo(){
  tiempoParar = setInterval(tiempo, 1000/30);
  resumeVideo();
}

var segundos;

function tiempo(){
  segundos = video.currentTime;
  console.log(segundos);
}
```

I have the same problem with currentTime property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you didn't assign the ID attribute of the element correctly:

change `id"vid"`
to `id="vid"`

Comment: Thanks I got stuck a lot of time for this.